# Facebook Graph API: Full event cover image from posts feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm fetching all Posts of a Facebook page using

```
startercenternrw/posts?type=event&fields=id,type,link,name,message,created_time,picture,object_id,full_picture,likes.limit(1).summary(true)&limit=10
```

Within the posts, I have the `full_picture` field. However, if the post is of `type=event`, then the `full_picture` is not "full". It is **always quadratic, thus often cropped**.

My question: How can I get the **full picture of an event** in the posts feed?

Is there a way to tell in the `posts` query that I do want the full (cover) picture?

As an alternative, I thought about fetching the actual event for every posts event item. Is there a way to do this in one (nested) query?

Comment: Are you looking for picture or cover? picture type=large can get you an image up to 200px by 200px, cover is the “full” one I think. (Not sure if those two necessarily need to be the same image though.) You have to go via the object_id here to get to them: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=2085248085053138%3Ffields%3Dpicture.type(large)%2Ccover&version=v2.12

Comment: But I did not manage to get that into your original request via field expansion, the usual `object_id{cover}` syntax does not seem to work here - so you might have to request them individually, I’m afraid (unless you or someone else can figure out a correct syntax for that in this place.) Otherwise, you could still group object ids in batch requests to at least save on HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm looking for cover, or simply the largest picture I can get :) Too bad it's not possible in one request. Thanks, though!